# Metal and Coordinate System Mapping

Tags: ios, swift, metal, vertex-shader, metalkit

I have a coordinate system where the **upper left** corner is (0,0) and the **bottom right** is (375,647)

[image]

In this system I have the coordinate of vertices like bellow :

```
var Vertices = [
  Vertex(x: 0,   y: 0,   z: 0, r: 1, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1),
  Vertex(x: 375, y: 0,   z: 0, r: 1, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1),
  Vertex(x: 375, y: 647, z: 0, r: 1, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1),
  Vertex(x: 0,   y: 647, z: 0, r: 1, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1),
 ]
```

so the vertices draw a rectangle that fills all my coordinates system. The screen size is (750,1294). My coordinate system represents this screen.

with Metal mormalized device coordinates use a left-handed coordinate system and map to positions in the viewport. Primitives are clipped to a box in this coordinate system and then rasterized. The lower-left corner of the clipping box is at an (x,y) coordinate of (-1.0,-1.0) and the upper-right corner is at (1.0,1.0).

[image]

How to draw my vertices with metal ?
I try to do

```
[RenderCommand setViewport: (MTLViewport){ 0.0, 0.0, 750, 1294, 0.0, 1.0 }];
```

but it's seam to not work, so maybe I miss something?

Comment: There are many more commands to shove down that render command encoder to get a vertex on the screen!  You need to set a vertex buffer, optionally an index buffer, a pipeline state (contains your vertex and fragment shaders) and finally issuing a draw call.

Comment: Checkout [Apple's Samples](https://developer.apple.com/metal/sample-code/) and [Warren Moore's amazing contribution](http://metalbyexample.com/).